# How do I write a custom migrate destination plugin in for a node type?

Tags: 8, migrations, entities

I've got a node type in Drupal 8 that uses field collections (from the module of the same name).  The Field Collections module doesn't yet have a working migration destination plugin, so what I'd like to do is use some kind of post-processing to (ugh) brute-force the field collection data into the nodes (note that I've tried the -dev version of Field Collection, and the destination plugin doesn't appear to be functional).  Note that my source is an SQL database and not a Drupal instance.

Here are the relevant files:

The migration definition file:

```
id: fm_quiz
label: FM Quiz
migration_group: quizzes
source:
  plugin: fm_quiz
  key: source
destination:
  plugin: fm_quiz
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: quiz
  title: title
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
```

The destination plugin:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\fm_quiz\Plugin\migrate\destination\FMQuiz.
 */

namespace Drupal\fm_quiz\Plugin\migrate\destination;

use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityContentBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;


/**
 * @MigrateDestination(
 *   id = "fm_quiz"
 * )
 */
class FMQuiz extends EntityContentBase {

  /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
  public function import(Row $row, array $old_destination_id_values = array()) {
    $node = $this->getEntity($row, $old_destination_id_values);
    print_r($node);

    return [$node->id()];
  }

}
```

At the moment, Drupal doesn't seem to want to recognize that this migration exists as written.

If I change the destination to "entity:node", then it imports the nodes as expected.  If I change the destination in both files to "entity:node:fm_quiz", then Drupal says that "Migration fm_quiz did not meet the requirements" (and provides no other information).

Am I doing something wrong, or is what I'm trying to do just not possible right now?  Do I need to just make an end run around the migration system?

Answer (score 4):

It's my understanding that your migration problem lies in the fact that you can't add a custom destination plugin for nodes. Your exact migration strategy is not entirely understood from your question, so I'm going to address only the part related to destination migration plugin, which might help you addressing the problem with adding custom logic to a migration process.

Destination plugins for entity migrations are indeed created by a deriver (see [MigrateEntity::getDerivativeDefinitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21Derivative%21MigrateEntity.php/function/MigrateEntity%3A%3AgetDerivativeDefinitions/8.2.x)) and adding custom destination plugins is not as straightforward as creating, for example, a custom source plugin which extends an existing source plugin, because destination entity type is determined from the ID of destination plugin (`entity:[name]`).

You can still create custom destination plugins for entity migrations in the following way:

Migration definition file:

```
id: fm_quiz
label: FM Quiz
migration_group: quizzes
source:
  plugin: fm_quiz
  key: source
destination:
  plugin: fm_quiz
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: quiz
  title: title
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
```

Custom migration destination plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fm_quiz\Plugin\migrate\destination;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityContentBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * @MigrateDestination(
 *   id = "fm_quiz"
 * )
 */
class FmQuizNodeDestination extends EntityContentBase {

  /** @var string $entityType */
  public static $entityType = 'node';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MigrationInterface $migration = NULL) {
    return parent::create($container, $configuration, 'entity:' . static::$entityType, $plugin_definition, $migration);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function import(Row $row, array $old_destination_id_values = array()) {
    // Add custom code here, if needed.
    return parent::import($row, $old_destination_id_values);
  }

}
```

Technically, it's the same class that `entity:node` destination plugin would use, but the `create()` method of the custom class *tricks* parent class to use storage of `node` entity type.

Comment: @Smartsheeteng My comment was about _extending_ destination plugins. Core already provides `entity:node` plugin by means or deriver, so if you add your own `@MigrateDestination(id = "entity:node")` destination plugin, it will not extend the existing plugin.

Comment: "it will not extend the existing plugin." -- to the contrary, it will. See the `mergeDerivativeDefinition` call [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Plugin%21Discovery%21DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php/function/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator%3A%3AgetDefinition/8.8.x). In other words, plugins can declare themselves as a derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Field Collection is deprecated in Drupal 8.  From [the project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection):

> [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) is likely to
>   replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way
>   to being deprecated. It is recommended to use paragraphs instead of
>   field collection for Drupal 8 projects.

You should replace your Field Collections with Paragraphs, and migrate Field Collection data into those.  Assuming that you're migrating from a Drupal 7 site, this process is mostly working as per [[META] Migrate support for importing field collections as paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2897021).  The only remaining task still open (at the time of this writing) is [Field collections deriver and base migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2911244), which is awaiting feedback from additional reviewers.

So it shouldn't be necessary for you to write a custom migration.